# Error when dealing with old and historical dates in Perl Time::Piece

Tags: perl, date, time

It seems `Time:Piece` gives me this error:
`Error parsing time at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Time/Piece.pm line 481.`
after the line where I use `strptime` with some old dates.

My code contains this:

```
my $ddate = "$month / $day / $year";
my $tmp = Time::Piece->strptime( $ddate, "%m / %d / %Y");
```

and $$date takes dates from a database using DBI that contains historical and old dates (dates back to the 10th and 9th centuries AD). How can I deal with this if there is any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use something other than Time::Piece if you want to deal with timestamps before 1970.

---

If you want to use the Gregorian calendar, you can use [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime).

If you want to use the Julian calendar, you can use [DateTime::Calendar::Julian](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Calendar::Julian).

The Gregorian calendar was introduced in September, 1582, and it was used universally by 1918. In between, calendar usage varied by country.

```
$ perl -MDateTime::Calendar::Julian -E'
   say
      DateTime::Calendar::Julian->new(year => 1013, month => 2, day => 22)
         ->strftime("%a");
'
Sun
```

---

Alternatively, [Date::Convert](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date::Convert) looks promising if you're just care about dates (not timestamps).

Comment: Thanks! Since you are experienced with perl, now I have another problem; for example, I use DateTime->new(year => 1013, month => 2, day => 22), when I print the day name, it gives me another day name than what shows up using `cal 1013` in linux. Is there something should be put in my ` DateTime->new()`?

Comment: I see the same discrepency. I don't know which is correct.

Comment: It is okay, Thank you for the answer.